# Система учета микросервисов

Tags: configuration, микросервисы

Доброго времени суток!

В прошлом году Вадим Мадисон из Avito читал на HighLoad++ доклад ["Что мы знаем о микросервисах"](https://habr.com/ru/post/429460/):

И вот еще Николай Голов с ["Концепцией персистентной ткани для контроля IT-инфраструктуры"](https://habr.com/ru/company/oleg-bunin/blog/462937/):

Там упоминался внутренний продукт Avito Atlas.

А существуют ли системы (желательно, open source), в которых я могу вести учет:

1. Виртуальных Машин и выделенных ресурсов под них
2. Прав доступа машинам
3. Сервисов, развернутых на этих машинах
4. Взаимосвязей сервисов
5. Баз Данных, с которыми они общаются
6. Ответственными за сервисы и группы сервисов 
   ?

Сейчас у меня два десятка хостов. На них более сотни виртуалок. На каждой виртуалке до 20 микросервисов, причем разной природы: WCF, Windows Services, .Net Core, Python. И есть четыре команды разработчиков, которых более 50 человек.

Жить с огромной табличкой в Confluence и Google Docs c группами хостов, ответственными и т.д. с каждым месяцем все сложнее.

Куда копать? И как нечто подобное назвать по-английски, чтобы правильно загуглить в яндексе?)

Comment: На мой взгляд полезно сразу дать подробности. Чем управляются виртуальные машины. Как запущены сервисы, в докер контейнерах ли, через какую ci? Как описываются взаимосвязи сервисов?

Comment: У нас, например, основное описано в docker-compose файлах (как минимум контейнеры, сети). Проекты ведутся в gitlab. Деплоятся тоже через gitlab ci. Апи гитлаба дает возможность получить много всего, в том числе, как я вижу, и информацию о раннерах https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html, то есть можно понять, какие сервисы где запущены. В нашем случае многое можно получить из апи гитлаба не регистрируя как-то все это отдельно, просто по факту деплоев.